# How to see object instance ids in Visual Studio Code debugger for C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to debug C# scripts for Unity, using the official Debugger for Unity extension, and Microsofts C# extension using Omnisharp.

But I can't seem to find a way to see what instance of an object a reference is using, all I can see is what type it has. Is there a way to show object id's in the Unity Debugger for Visual Studio Code?

Is it possible? Maybe from the Debug Console?

Edit: I mean general C# object id:s, not necessarily GameObjects in the scene.

Comment: There isn't as far as I know. But you can query or `Debug.Log` the object's `Name` property, assuming the objects in question have unique names in the hierarchy. If not use something like `Debug.Draw....` to highlight the objects in the scene, maybe in a try/catch block.

Comment: Also, cant test right now but I think if you click the error message in the console while not debugging in VS it will highlight the object in the hierarchy. I could be wrong but worth a look.

Comment: @Absinthe Thank you for the help, what you suggest will most likely be useful to me also, but right now the object ids I'm looking for is general C# object instances, and not necessarily GameObjects in the scene.